# General questions about database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to create e-learning platform. So users will have a lot of things to choose (mostly available to view only for them) like:

- add note
- add movies to favorite
- rate the instructor

And few options that auto save for each user like:

- unanswered questions
- wrong answer questions
- movies in progress  (user saw only 2 min from 5)

**So what database or method I schould use for store that kind of data?**

I do not want to use cookies because it needs to be save on user account and not on  browser. User need to have that all on every browser or mobile device.

I wondering about json but...if I do so each user I'd will be available to view...so schould I use MySQL?

Comment: _..so schould I use mysql?.._ Yes, but it sounds you need a developer who has done it before....otherwise start reading basics of php and mysql, and practice a lot

Comment: You can use what you want according to what you can do...mysql is one solution for sure

Comment: So now. I will need to create new table for each user ye?? Or. Can I save array inside a cell?

Comment: No and no. You should read an introductory database tutorial (at least as far as the point where it explains joins, foreign keys, and many-to-many relationships).

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some basic studying of the fundamentals before embarking on something as complex as this. Break the solution down into the component parts and study how each element works on the basic level. As well as not needing tables for each user in the database showing a fundamental lack of understanding, your point about not wanting to use cookies shows a lack of basic knowledge of what cookies are for or what they do.

Comment: Give yourself some much simpler requirements which allow you to focus on learning the underlying technology instead of the business rules.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would recommend that you build your own data logger, what i mean by this is build yourself a place to store every users data like an eManager if you would like.

Once this has been built you can then assign the eLearning courses using an ID to each of the users profile on your "eManager". Allowing you too keep track of each users progress etc.

The "eManager" could also save the users notes/wrong answers/unanswered questions, you could create surveys with a slider rating to rate the user. Honestly the limit is endless.

You can receive the data in two different ways:

- (Personal) Either you can request that your users email you requesting a username and you generate a password and send it out to the user.
- (Commercial) You build your eManager to recieve the data from the website which isnt too difficult to do.

It will be a long process and to answer your question in a different view practice SQL/PHP that would be your base make sure you can run more advanced query's and can confidently edit your DB etc.

Anymore questions just let me know, thanks.

Comment: I doubt this vague statements will help OP... _(Personal) (Commercial)_ By saying things like that you will only confuse OP and other ppl who will read this in future.... _It will be a long process and to answer your question..._ Exactly

Comment: @B001ᛦ Nothing is vague about it. You recommended he start reading SQL basics. I do not see how you recommending the OP to read SQL basics will help, ty

Comment: _Anymore questions just let me know.._ Yes, there are 100 questions coming up when reading your "answer"

Comment: Thanks for answer. So basically I need to create api... that will connected to my db yes?

Comment: @Piotr Yes my friend eLearning sites work this way i have worked with them myself and its a long process but you will get there with trial and error

Comment: _he will know exactly what he needs to do upon reading my answer_ This is not an answer, and I really dont know why they accepted those vague lines, maybe because of doing a favor to you... there is a lot more behind the process as you mentioned by yourself...

Comment: @B001ᛦOfcourse there is alot more behind my answer but i cannot go into depth about a step by step guide of how to build an api. The OP asked for a method, so i gave them a method. You cannot say i am Vague when all the OP asked for was a 'way' to do something, thank you bye.

Comment: The thing is. Before I ask questions I know the answer and the thing i have to create api. But... becouse it is long process I had to ask questions as a noob. Becouse was lookin for faster solution...

Comment: No problem at all also i do not think there is a faster solution but you can do some google research, tha may help